# Can std::string::c_str() be used whenever a string literal is expected?

Tags: c++, casting, c-strings, string-literals, rapidjson

I would guess that the last two lines in this code should compile.

```
#include "rapidjson/document.h"

int main(){
    using namespace rapidjson ;
    using namespace std ;

    Document doc ;
    Value obj(kObjectType) ;
    obj.AddMember("key", "value", doc.GetAllocator()) ; //this compiles fine
    obj.AddMember("key", string("value").c_str(), doc.GetAllocator()) ; //this does not compile!
}
```

My guess would be wrong, though. One line compiles and the other does not.

The `AddMember` method has several variants as documented [here](http://rapidjson.org/classrapidjson_1_1_generic_value.html), but beyond that... why is the return of `.c_str()` not equivalent to a string literal?

My understanding was that where ever a string literal was accepted, you could pass `string::c_str()` and it should work.

PS: I'm compiling with VC++ 2010.

**EDIT:**
The lack of `#include <string>`  is not the problem. It's already included by `document.h`

**This is the error:**

```
error C2664: 'rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding> &rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding>::AddMember(rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding> &,rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding> &,Allocator &)'
: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [4]' to 'rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding> &'
    with
    [
        Encoding=rapidjson::UTF8<>,
        Allocator=rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>
    ]
    and
    [
        Encoding=rapidjson::UTF8<>
    ]
```

---

**EDIT2:**
Please ignore the fact that `.c_str()` is called on a temporal value. This example is just meant to show the compile error. The actual code uses a string variable.

---

**EDIT3:**
Alternate version of the code:

```
string str("value") ;
obj.AddMember("key", "value", doc.GetAllocator()) ; //compiles
obj.AddMember("key", str, doc.GetAllocator()) ; // does not compile
obj.AddMember("key", str.c_str(), doc.GetAllocator()) ; // does not compile
```

Comment: Did you include `<string>`? Also, `main()` always returns `int`.

Comment: A string literal has array type, while `c_str()` returns a pointer. It's possible to have function overloads that can tell the difference (but fairly unfriendly to make them behave significantly differently).

Comment: Lifetime of `string("value").c_str()` is very limited. so unless a copy of the `const char*` is done, you may have dangling pointer.

Comment: You forgot to include the compiler's error message.

Comment: The AddMember() documentation link leads to http://rapidjson.org/structrapidjson_1_1_generic_string_ref.html which has an example explaining they are trying to catch what you are doing.

Comment: `void main` has never been valid in either C or C++. Please don't post code with `void main` since it makes it less easy to test your code, and since it misleads novice programmers. FTFY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation you linked to, it seems like you are trying to call the overload of `AddMember` taking two `StringRefType`s (and an `Allocator`). `StringRefType` is a typedef for `GenericStringRef<Ch>`, which has two overloaded constructors taking a single argument:

```
template<SizeType N>
GenericStringRef(const CharType(&str)[N]) RAPIDJSON_NOEXCEPT;

explicit GenericStringRef(const CharType *str);
```

When you pass a string literal, the type is `const char[N]`, where `N` is the length of the string + 1 (for the null terminator). This can be implicitly converted to a `GenericStringRef<Ch>` using the first constructor overload. However, `std::string::c_str()` returns a `const char*`, which cannot be converted implicitly to a `GenericStringRef<Ch>`, because the second constructor overload is declared `explicit`.

The error message you get from the compiler is caused by it choosing another overload of `AddMember` which is a closer match.

Comment: Note that the actual argument that compiler reacts to in the quoted diagnostic, is a literal or an array declared as such, a `char const [4]`, not a c_str() call.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The compiler error is also referring to parameter 1. Hence, the last sentence in my answer.

Comment: Ok so basically, the `AddMember` method accepts string literals but not `char` pointers.

Answer (score 5):

The `std::string::c_str()` method returns a `char const*`. The type of a string literal is `char const[N]` where `N` is the number of characters in the string (including the null terminator). Correspondingly, the result of `c_str()` can **not** be used in **all** places where a string literal can be used!

I'd be surprised if the interface you are trying to call requires a `char` array, though. That is, in your use it should work. It is more likely that you need to include `<string>`.

Comment: You also can't pass c_str to something that expects a char* (not const), array or not. And you have to also be careful that the function you're passing it to doesnt store the pointer somewhere for later, which will compile but ultimately blow up.

Comment: @JasonC: you can't pass a string literal to something expecting a `char*`, either! The C backward compatibility of the the special conversion was always deprecated and removed with C++11.

Answer (score 4):

even if this code compiled:

```
obj.AddMember("key2", string("value").c_str(), doc.GetAllocator());
```

You cannot guarantee that it is safe.

The const char* returned by std::string::c_str() will be valid until the end of this statement.

If the `AddMember` method stores a copy of the string itself, all well and good. If it stores a pointer then you're doomed. You need knowledge of the inner workings of AddMember before you can reason about the correctness of your code.

I suspect the authors have already thought of this and have constructed overloads that demand that you either send in a `std::string` object (or equivalent) or a string literal reference (`template<std::size_t N> void AddMember(const char (&str)[N])`)

Even if this is not what they had in mind, they might be looking to protect you from yourself, in case you inadvertently send in an invalid pointer.

While seemingly an inconvenience, this compile time error indicates a possibly-faulty program. It's a tribute to the library's authors. Because compile time errors are a gazillion times more useful than runtime errors.

Comment: _You need knowledge of the inner workings of AddMember before you can reason about the correctness of your code._ - Well, you need to carefully read the documentation. But being careful with this construct is good advice and I second your tribute to the library's authors.

Answer (score 2):

Re

> **”** why is the return of `.c_str()` not equivalent to a string literal

A string literal is a zero-terminated string in an array with size known at compile time.

`c_str()` produces a pointer to (the first item in) a zero-terminated string in an array with size known only at run-time.

Usually a string literal expression will be used in a context where the expression *decays* to pointer to first item, but in some special cases it does not decays. These cases include

- binding to a reference to array,
- using the `sizeof` operator, and
- forming a larger literal by compile time concatenation of string literals (simply writing them in order).

I think that's an exhaustive list.

---

The error message you cite,

> **”** cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [4]' to 'rapidjson::GenericValue &

… **does not match your presented code**

```
#include "rapidjson/document.h"

int main(){
    using namespace rapidjson ;
    using namespace std ;

    Document doc ;
    Value obj(kObjectType) ;
    obj.AddMember("key1", "value", doc.GetAllocator()) ; //this compiles fine
    obj.AddMember("key2", string("value").c_str(), doc.GetAllocator()) ; //this does not compile!
}
```

Nowhere in this code is there a three character long string literal.

Hence the claims that “this compiles” and “this does not compile”, are not very trustworthy.

You

- should have quoted the actual error message and actual code (at least one of them is not what you had when you compiled), and
- should have quoted the documentation of the function you're calling.

Also, note that the actual argument that compiler reacts to in the quoted diagnostic, is a literal or an array declared as such, not a `c_str()` call.

Comment: Maybe VC++ is not counting the null termination?

Comment: @GetFree: It must count it. It's part of the array size.

Comment: Oh, your are right, I just realized that I added a `"1"` and `"2"` to the `"key"` string while I was writing the question. I'll fix that.